# Jquery custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm thinking about using custom attributes in Jquery to avoid using class or id attributes, to not interfere with the html designers.

Taking into account this idea, the html should be pieces like:

```
<ul Jquery="CommonUl">
    <li Jquery="CommonLi"></li>     
    <li Jquery="CommonLi"></li>
    <li Jquery="CommonLi"></li>
    <li Jquery="CommonLi"></li>
    <li Jquery="CommonLi"></li>
</ul>
```

- Do you think this is a good approach?
- What is your opinion about the W3C validation of these custom attributes?
- Do you know any way to program with Jquery without interfering with the work of the html designers?
- About the performance, I suppose that with class attributes or ids the jquery selectors are faster than using a custom attribute and filtering functions like "contains, etc...". Is this right?

Comment: My opinion about W3C validation for this is that it will fail. :) Are you familiar with jQuery's `.data()`? (It won't help if you need to store the data directly in the markup, though)

Comment: Actually @Pekka it will, with jQuery 1.4.3!  A call to `.data("foo")` will pick up the value of `data-foo="value"` on an element.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, but `data-*` is not valid in HTML 4...

Comment: Oh yes that's true, @Pekka, but all the cool people use HTML5 now :-)

Comment: @Pointy yeah,! :) But it's not for everyone yet. Not with the spotty browser support....

Comment: Not everything supports `<video>` and `<canvas>` but even IE6 will put up with the HTML5 @DOCTYPE and basic markup. The whole point of the HTML5 "spec" is to encompass actual current browser behavior.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a win to me. How are invalid custom attributes any less ‘in the way’ for designers than a `class` or `id`? Seems to me they'd be *more* likely to get mangled/lost in a visual design app.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can do this, use [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) though ([part of the HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)), like this:

```
<li data-something="CommonLi"></li>
```

jQuery even has built-in support for these in 1.4.3+, for example:

```
$("li").data("something") //"CommonLi"
```

For your other questions:

- They'll *validate* if it's HTML5 - but won't *break* anything in HTML4
- This shouldn't interfere with the designer, but it'll depend on *which* designer
- If you're fetching from an element, the performance is the same as any other attribute

Comment: This will be invalid in HTML 4 though, so if it's important to support older browsers and be W3C valid it's not an option sadly. If that's not a problem, this is the best way to go

Comment: @Pekka - I agree, but being 100% valid isn't as important as being 100% functional...if there wasn't a gap in the spec where these were needed, they wouldn't have been added in HTML5 :)  Upping the HTML5 DOCTYPE should take care of both sides here.

Comment: Hi, thanks in advance... Great response. The thing is that probably we will not use HTML 5 aparently will not be finished until 2012.

Comment: @Nick yeah, true. I meant it more as a side note for when you need W3c validity e.g. for a build process - that might need another route until HTML 5 can be fully used.

Comment: @Jose3d - HTML5 is mostly HTML4 with some additions...you can use the features supported now.  There's nothing new about this in HTML5, **nothing** new, only that the validator no longer complains.

Comment: @Jose you can use this in HTML 4 already without problems, it just won't validate

Comment: Ok, then i understand. The actual validators will be not validate, but yes the new HTML5. 

Thanks for the useful discussion.
Regards.
Jose

Comment: NOTE: data-something apparently has to be all lowercase as using an uppercase letter in the "something" part won't work. Don't know if this is the official spec or just Chrome's interpretation.

Comment: What about the performance of using custom jQuery data attributes to store actual javascript objects? if i use `element.setAttribute('data-blah', {x:1,y:2})` it becomes a string "[object Object]" stored in the attribute `data-blah`. jQuery's .data() mechanism allows one to store anything -- so `$(element).data({x:1, y:2})` will work. Given this difference I cannot believe that the performance is exactly the same as fetching any other attribute. So does anyone know if there's significant overhead with .data()? I'm planning on storing small objects on a few thousand elements...

Comment: @lucian303 Good catch. I went to [that secret place where people could write all their passwords and nobody would ever read them](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) and found out that, indeed, it has to be all lowercase. Which, granted, is pretty counterintuitive! (but I thank them; uppercase should be left to COBOL, SQL and DOS batch files).

Comment: You can use capitalized attributes if you use jQuery's attr, such as $(this).attr("data-Something");

Answer (score 14):

if you're planning to have several attribute I suggest to set a unique namespaced attribute, e.g.

```
<li data-yourapp>...</li>
```

and use that attribute like an hashtable

```
$("li").data("yourapp", { 
   points  : 2000,
   life    : 1,
   weapons : {
      firegun  : 0,
      missiles : 12
   }
});
```

in this way you will reduce element access and you will retrieve all custom data once

Comment: Nice... didn't know you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally recommend you to using jquery builtin method for saving data with each element.
following is the code snippet for saving data:

```
$("ul").data("CommonUl");
$("li").data("CommonLi");
```

Comment: First of all, thanks... I didnt knew this way of store data foreach element. The thing is that probably i will not need to say something like: "all ul's and li's will have the following data attached", instead there will be some specific elements (maybe in the page there is 4 ul, and i will like to apply this to one and not by position)... 
Best Regards.