# HTML, custom element attribute, will work on all browsers?

Tags: jquery, html

I create a plugin, and I like to have some extra attributes in my HTML elements. I know that if I create my own custom attributes the HTML document will not valid, but this is not the problem. I just wondering, in that case it will be posible to access that atributes with jQuery ?

ie:

```
<div id="c" my-custom-attr="myValue" data-my-custom-attr="another-value">
    Content here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $att1 = $('#c').attr('my-custom-attr');
    $att2 = $('#c').attr('data-my-custom-attr');
</script>
```

Will create any problem with any browser the above code ? :?

Comment: You use `.data( 'my-custom-attr' )` for the second one...

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145636/jquery-custom-attributes

Comment: The question is not the how. I know how can I use the data. What I like to do is to totaly seperate the JavaScript from HTML context. That means that I can't pass variables into JavaScript that are coming from PHP execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While no one can say it will work in *all* browsers; your code should not cause any problems in the major modern browsers. I would suggest using the `data-*` HTML5 naming convention as you've done in your second example.

As a side note; in your second example, you can access the attribute in two ways using jQuery 1.4.3+

```
<div id="c" data-my-custom-attr="another-value">
    Content here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Both produce the same output //
    console.log($('#c').attr('data-my-custom-attr'));
    console.log($('#c').data('my-custom-attr'));
</script>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at jQuery's `data` method. You can store attributes against elements using it. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: This is a good way to store data, but I like to seperate my HTML from JavaScript. Waht I mean, I like to have my JavaScript into on file, and not some Javascript into HTML context and some javascript into *.js files

Comment: Have you had a look at jQuery's Plugin Authoring article? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Chris, the problem is not how to Use the jQuery. What I do, I have some variables in PHP, then I print out the HTML and I have to pass some variables to jQuery, witch in turn are specific to several div elements. Also the jQuery is not into the HTML page, is external, and I need to allow the jQuery to read that variables from HTML. How can I do that ?