# any generalized functions for fadeIn fadeOut?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myfirstDiv').click(function () {
        $('#seconDiv').fadeIn("fast");
    });
    $('#closeBtn').click(function () {
        $('#seconDiv').fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

there is multiple usage of these functions in my site, with different ids for Div and Buttons.
How could I generalize these functions for every Div and Button?

Comment: Make a custom jQuery plugin that wraps a call to the function you want and use it.

Comment: What does you markup look like?

Comment: i have many divs like "#myfirstDiv" and "#secondDiv" for doing same work on them, i want only 2 generalize functions as above instead of writing these fadeIn fadeOut functions for every Div and Close Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a plugin that takes in the second div and the button to close it:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        FadeInOut: function(divTwo, closeBtn) {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).click(function() {
                    $(divTwo).fadeIn("fast");
                });
                $(closeBtn).click(function() {
                    $(divTwo).fadeOut("fast");
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NcNaH/)

Answer (score 3):

1. Define a class for the button div
2. Define a class for the fading div
3. Create a custom attribute `data-target` in the `div` button
4. Create a custom attribute `data-action` in the `div` button
5. Have your jQuery look for all button div elements (select by class) and link them to their targets, according to their actions (show/fadeIn or hide/fadeOut)

This way, no matter how many buttons or divs, your jQuery will "automagically" link them, if they are correctly set.

Sorry, no code for now, but this approach works.

**Update**

Some links to help you achieve this approach:

- [Jquery custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145636/jquery-custom-attributes)
- [jQuery's class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [jQuery's bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution to generalize these fadeIn and fadeOut functions.
you can see this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbW2u/13/)


may be it would help any other.