# How to use value of own attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<button own-attribute="value1 value2">Button</button>
```

i want to use the values `value1` & `value2` of `own-attribute` in javascript to make changes in the style of `<button>`.

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145636/jquery-custom-attributes

Comment: It's not copy of that one. The 'jQuery' do a quite big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a CSS only solution you can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target such elements:

```
button[own-attribute~="value1"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

Using `attributeName~=value` you can target a single value, if your attribute contains a  space separated list of values.

---

Note, however, that custom attributes should use the [`data-`-prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to prevent collisions with native attribute names.

- [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-%2a)
- [How to use `data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

---

If you want to just retriebe the element to further process it in JS, use the same selector:

```
// to contain just one of the values
var el = document.querySelector( 'button[own-attribute~="value1"]' );

// to contain both values, no matter the order
var otherEl = document.querySelector( 'button[own-attribute~="value1"][own-attribute~="value2"]' );
```

Comment: i had tried css custom styling but its need lot of coding for two values in one attribute. Please suggest any code in javascript to use the value of custom attribute.

Comment: Might be a reasonable idea to point out this is CSS, since he specifies Javascript specifically in his question.

Comment: and i don't want to use `data-` as prefix --> @Sirko

Comment: @Preet What do you mean by "a lot of coding for two values"? You could use the same selectors in JavaScript's `querySelector()` as well. If it is just about retrieving the values, use `getAttribute()`.

Comment: can you please suggest the javascript code for two values. @Sirko

Comment: @Preet I'm not sure I understand, what you need this for. See my edit please. If this does not help you, maybe add some more context (what do you exactly want to do?) to the question.

Comment: @Preet So what's the reason for not using plain CSS, if you just want to do styling?